# how to affect another div with similar(Unique) id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uniqueidentifier

as seen in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yasinallana/m26YS/) i want to change the value of another div using the unique id of one div but i dont know how to make that possible it only works for the first div not the second one

**Code:**

html

```
<div class="a" data-u="1399037905154655004">a</div>
<div class="a" data-u="1399037905154655009">b</div>
<br>
<div class="test" id="id1399037905154655004">ini text 1</div>
<div class="test" id="id1399037905154655009">ini text 2</div>
```

Javascript

```
var id=$(".a").attr('data-u');//get the id
$("#id"+id).text("23456");//using the unique id change the text
```

**Note:**I donot want to use any form of click event

Comment: if you want to have each .test with the same text [http://jsfiddle.net/m26YS/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/m26YS/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), As `.data()` is to get `data-attribute` of the element

```
$(".a").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('u');
    $("#id"+id).text("23456") // Will set same text for both divs
});
```

*As per your comment*

If you prefer `.attr()` then try this

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-u'); // .attr instead of .data()
```

***Note***: If you're using `data-attr` anywhere in your mark-up, it is recommended to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` to get that attribute.

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m26YS/3/)

### [**Demo With .attr()**](http://jsfiddle.net/m26YS/4/)

Comment: i prefer using `.attr()`

Comment: ok a little side-note how do i call a function while it is in the each loop because im getting an error in google chrome

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ago is not defined

Comment: That error may be somewhere else, it doesn't seem from your this code, You might be using a variable `ago` without declaring it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51900/discussion-between-dhaval-marthak-and-mr-coder)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var id = $(".a").map(function(){return $(this).attr("data-u");}).get();

  $("#id"+id[0]).text("23456"); 
  $("#id"+id[1]).text("23456");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class, to target your divs, so your selector is returning more than one element, you need to loop:

```
$(".a").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('u');
    $("#id"+id).text("23456")
});
```